# Logs from Vector not getting to Loki

Tags: grafana-loki

I have three docker containers all running locally, vector, loki, and grafana, all on the same network.  I am sending syslog messages to vector and transforming them.  I have two sinks, one "console" and one "loki".  I see the transformed messages in the vector service logs, so the console sink is working.  But loki does not seem to be receiving the messages.  I can docker exec -it into the vector container and can successfully ping the loki endpoint so I know that there is connectivity.  But nothing seems to be happening when I look at the loki logs, and if I query loki I don't receive anything back.  My vector configuration looks like this:

```
[sources.my_syslog]
type = "socket"
address = "0.0.0.0:8686"
mode="tcp"
path = "/path/to/socket"
encoding.codec = "line"
tls.enabled = false

[sinks.console]
inputs = ["my_syslog"]
type = "console"
encoding.codec = "json"

[sinks.my_sink_id]
type = "loki"
inputs = ["my_syslog"]
endpoint = "http://sw-4732-sunset-loggly-loki-1:3100"
tenant_id = "tenant1"
encoding.codec = "json"

  [sinks.my_sink_id.healthcheck]
    enabled = false

  [sinks.my_sink_id.labels]
    source = 'model'
```

I have disabled healthcheck because it's failing (because I'm bringing all the containers up together and loki isn't ready).  But after everything is up and running, vector is able to connect as I mention above.

This query

```
curl -G -s "http://sw-4732-sunset-loggly-loki-1:3100/loki/api/v1/query_range" \
  --data-urlencode 'query={}' \
  --data-urlencode 'start=-1h'
```

returns nothing.

Comment: Unless I missed something, query `{}` is not valid query for loki. [It requires at least one regexp or equality matcher that does not have an empty-compatible value](https://play.grafana.org/explore?panes=%7B%229Sm%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22expr%22:%22%7B%7D%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-6h%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&schemaVersion=1&orgId=1)

Comment: Can you try something like `{host=~".+"}` instead?

Comment: Yes sorry I also tried {host=~".+"} and that returns nothing.  Removed the time restriction as well.  So I'm pretty sure loki has not received any logs but I just don't understand why.  It must be something with my vector configuration but vector is not giving me any errors.